# Gaps and Islands but with a lot of nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum, gaps-and-islands

I have source data like following table and trying to get desired output.

Basically I want to running total until status changes to fail.

| date | id | tg_id | status | DESIRED_OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/31/2019 | 123456 |  |  | 0 |
| 1/1/2020 | 123456 |  |  | 0 |
| 1/2/2020 | 123456 |  |  | 0 |
| 1/3/2020 | 123456 | 752 | FAIL | 1 |
| 1/4/2020 | 123456 |  |  | 1 |
| 1/5/2020 | 123456 |  |  | 1 |
| 1/6/2020 | 123456 |  |  | 1 |
| 1/7/2020 | 123456 |  |  | 1 |
| 1/8/2020 | 123456 | 752 | FAIL | 2 |
| 1/9/2020 | 123456 |  |  | 2 |
| 1/10/2020 | 123456 |  |  | 2 |

I know this gaps and island problem but the issue I am running into is when the status is not fail and it's nulls I am not sure how to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually just a cumulative windowed sum:

```
select *, 
  IsNull(Sum(case when status = 'FAIL' then 1 end) 
           over(partition by id order by date)
  , 0) as Desired_Output
from t;
```

Demo [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UcWMnFZz)

Comment: this will give sum but then where there are gaps it should give 0.

Example from 1/3 till 1/7 it should carry that 1. Right now it will only give 1 for 1/3 and rest is 0

Comment: @PoojanPatel The [Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UcWMnFZz) matches the desired results in your question - have you viewed it?

Comment: Hi @stu , yes I saw it however I think for same ID if tg_id also changes then might need to start another transaction. Meaning for 752 it's fine I was thinking maybe need to include this in partition by as well.

Comment: Ok well that's not documented at all in your question there is no mention of this column, but that's probably very easy for you to test?